# How to prepare dataset for a multi-task-learning network with a yolo output layer?

Tags: java, yolo, deeplearning4j, dl4j, computation-graph

I have a convolutional neural network with a Yolo output-layer and multiple regression output-layers(I just mapped extra output layers to a typical Yolo CNN) using a computation graph. The problem I have is with the dataset, for the Yolo output I have pascal-voc `.xml` files and for the regression outputs `.csv` files i.e.

**OBJECT DETECTION DATA**

```
            InputSplit[] data = new FileSplit(image_dir, NativeImageLoader.ALLOWED_FORMATS, random).sample(path_filter, split_weight0,split_weight1);
            InputSplit trainData = data[0];
            InputSplit testData = data[1];

            ObjectDetectionRecordReader recordReaderTrain = new ObjectDetectionRecordReader(height, width, nChannels,gridH, gridW, new VocLabelProvider(DIR));
            ObjectDetectionRecordReader recordReaderTest = new ObjectDetectionRecordReader(height, width, nChannels,gridH, gridW, new VocLabelProvider(DIR));
            recordReaderTrain.initialize(trainData);
            recordReaderTest.initialize(testData);

            //commented out since MultiDataSetIterator is meant to be used instead  
            //RecordReaderDataSetIterator train = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReaderTrain, batchSize, 1, 1, true);
            //RecordReaderDataSetIterator test = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReaderTest, 1, 1, 1, true);
            //train.setPreProcessor(new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1));
            //test.setPreProcessor(new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1));
```

**REGRESSION DATA**

```
 RecordReader r0= new CSVRecordReader(',');
 r0.initialize(new FileSplit(new File( DIR+"/r0.csv")));

 RecordReader r1=...
 ...
```

I tried to implement the Multi-Task Learning example from [RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator Example 2](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nn-computationgraph)

```
MultiDataSetIterator train = new RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.Builder(batchSize)
                .addReader("rr", recordReaderTrain)
                .addReader("r0", r0)
                .addInput("???")//recordReaderTrain.getInputImagesData() ?
                .addOutput("rr")//recordReaderTrain.getVocLabelData() ?
                .addOutput("r0")
                .addOutput("r1")
                ... //addOutput -> r2,r3,...
                .build();
```

How can I correctly configure the input from the record reader that feeds from the `VocLabelProvider` with data preprocessing or is it possible to wrap the `MultiDataSetIterator` around another dataset iterator i.e. a multi dataset iterator from two dataset iterators from the `.xml` object-detection  and `.csv` regression files

Comment: specifically I need help with an example that implements a `MultiDataSetIterator` with `ObjectDetectionRecordReader` and multiple  `RecordReader`s